# Trigger an event before `` system call is carried out

Tags: ruby, kernel

I'm looking to check before a system call using either system or `` is executed to make sure the call was made from a specific module.

I don't want to use it to sanitize or validate the command but just make sure only one module can make these calls.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
module BacktickURI
  alias_method :standard_back_tick_call, :`  #` #Comment for fixing Notepad++ highlighting, needs even back ticks
  alias_method :standard_system_call, :system

  def `(uri)#`
      standard_back_tick_call(uri)
  end

  def system uri
     standard_system_call uri
 end
end
```

Edit: The code above isn't the full process, it's just the bit that does the task I was looking for, updating the system and backtick methods.

Alias_method shifts scope with include, preventing the circular reference or something like that.

Comment: what is the point of aliasing `system` here? It seems you have a circular reference in the `system` method definition. Also, I think it would be easier to just create a wrapper method and call that from the code instead of backticks.

Comment: alias_method shifts scope at runtime so when I use include the four methods are introduced as separate entities (I think that's what's going on). The purpose of this is to prevent me and others from working with any project it's embedded into and accidentally making a system call when they shouldn't. I've used a whitelisting approach for management. If the user needs to do something they can manually turn the feature off via a switch added to the module.